# Swagger redirects to localhost

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

Every time I attempt to invoke any `REST API` from `Swagger` running on external server it tries to invoke API from `localhost`. In result every request URL tends to look like

```
"https://{my_local_host_ip}/api/dictionary/get" instead of "https://dev-server/api/dictionary/get"
```

Can't figure out what cause this issue so i appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: We cannot help you without details. Which kind of external server ? Version of Java ? Swagger ?

Comment: Usually BeanConfig::setBasePath handles this if you correctly set the path to point to another server, if not set it will default to relative path on current server.

Comment: @AlexC Thanks for answering but could you be more specific? There's no BeanConfig class in my project. I founded only SwaggerConfiguration class but have no idea what to change.

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-RESTEasy-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5  BeanConfig is used to configure swgger on startup and one of the options is to set a base path.  I don't know what SwaggerConfiguration is, there is one in jhipster that I googled but I don't know if that is what you are using.  Look for a way to set a base path.

Comment: Actually the best way to do that on BeanConfig is using:  BeanConfig,setHost(String): Sets the host (including a port) for the API URLs. Does not include the schemes nor context root.